# Export with jspdf - bootstrap icons not exported properly

Tags: angular, jspdf

I am trying to export a pdf with this icon.
But instead of showing the icon, it shows 'ok'

Do you have any workaround for this issue?

`<i class='bi bi-info-circle text-info'></i>`